# Connect action of a XIB loaded from a custom class to a storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, xib, ibaction

I'm trying to create a reusable component to display some photo collection.
The basic flow is the following :

- First view : `View`. It contains my so called library, designed programmatically and loaded from storyboard by assigning a custom class
- I take a photo in a modal view, openend from the 'take picture' button
- Once the photo is saved on disk, I ask `PhotoLib` to create a new `PhotoCell` from the photo path

I would like my `PhotoCell` to be touch enabled so when I tap it, it opens the second view in a modal way, but from what I read I cannot do this from my `PhotoCell` or the UIImageView inside (not a controller).

So how can I do ? `View` is embedded in a NavigationController, even if not shown in the screenshots below.

Thank you !

[image: View from XCode]

Comment: Can't you add a button with style "custom" above imageview and work with this? I did something like that If I understood your idea. Maybe you should show your storyboard and part of code to clarify.

Comment: I could, but I still don't know how to connect its IBAction to my code. I will try to post more information if I can sum it up

Comment: Yeah, I've re-read your question. Maybe you'll need protocol in Photocell class that has method -(void)didTapPhotoCell:(Photocell*)self or something like that, implement your view as delegate and act from then?

Comment: Yes ! This is quite working. Since i'm creating my `PhotoCell` elements from `PhotoLib`, and wanted to assign `View` as `PhotoCell.delegate`, i tried to do something like this (from `PhotoLib`): `c.delegate = self.superview` or even `c.delegate = self.superview.superview` (where c is my photocell) but it doesn't work. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create Photocell in photolib, then photolib should implementing delegate methods from photocell. But photolib itself is not rootviewcontroller, so it should declare delegate methods itself, and the containing view should implement it.

Basically you pass Photocell from itself to Photolib (which implements delegate method

```
-(void) openPhotoCell:(Photocell*)cell
{
  [self.delegate openPhotocell:(Photocell*)cell];
}
```

, then it passes it to View, which in its turn opens it.

It may seem like pulling a tooth from an ear, but actually it's quite working and if you write good self-explanatory code, it's not a problem. I'm currently working on some big project with tens views and controllers and it works pretty good and nobody has problem with that.

If you have more layers, then maybe you should look into NSNotification.

Hope it helped, I'd be glad to explain more.

UPD:

Links:

[about delegates in cocoa fundamentals guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)

[delegation pattern in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Comment: it works well but I decided to create a property `delegate`in PhotoLib, and each time I create a `PhotoCell` I set its delegate from it. I thought it would be more... obvious, since photo lib itself doesn't need a delegate, but maybe if I need to create a fully functional and easy to use library then I would have to do it better

Comment: @dvkch don't worry, what you did is pretty normal. And yes, in future you may want to reimplement it. But you don't have to, if your project won't get more complicated.

Comment: alright ! thank you ! I would like to set your post as the accepted answer, but could you just add a link explaining quickly delegates in it for future readers ?``

Comment: @dvkch added links. I guess you meant those links.